# Detect if tab is active? (different from focus)

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events

My Javascript uses a timer to refresh the CSS of a page. I like to have it run when Safari is in the background and I'm making changes in my code editor, but I don't want it to run when it's not in the active browser tab.

`window.blur` and `window.focus` get triggered when another tab is in focus, but they also get triggered when the tab is active and Safari is in the background, so they don't help me here.

How do I detect solely if the tab my Javascript is running in is currently active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3C has a working draft for tracking this exact situation: [the page visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-page-visibility-20110602/). It looks like Chrome is the only browser that supports it, currently with [an experimental API](http://code.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility.html). You can try it out with this little function in the Web Inspector console:

```
function tattle() {
  console.log(document.webkitVisibilityState);
}

document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", tattle, false);
```

After playing around with it, I think this is exactly what I need. Basically document.webkitHidden is only false if the document is in the active tab of its window, regardless of whether other windows or applications are active.

Comment: from reading the referenced chrome page, i think i found an error. it states <q>`document.webkitHidden` Returns true if the page is in a state considered to be hidden to the user, and false otherwise.<q>. in this answer it says that it is true if the document is the active tab in its window, when in fact it would be false.

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariextensions

Comment: Those are only available to Safari extensions

Answer (score -1):

try something like onmouseover..